# Renaming folder with filename in PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell, renaming

I've got a lot of folders that I want to batch rename using PowerShell. In each folder there are a lot of different files with different extensions. What I want to do is to rename the folder with the *.nfo filename.

Example:

C:\foldertest\TEST\
In this folder these files reside:
JPG.jpg
NFO.nfo
TXT.txt
WAV.wav

After running a script I want the folder to be renamed like the *.nfo:
C:\foldertest\NFO\
I need a solution that works on > 1 folder at a time.

This is what I have (not working o/c):
`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\foldertest\" | Where-Object{$_.PSisContainer} | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $new1Name = Get-ChildItem $_ -Filter "*.nfo" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace $new1Name
}`

UPDATE:
I am still having problems. The solution (see below) seemed to work at first, but only sometimes. Let's say on 30% of the folders. Then this error happens on the rest:
`Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Users\STOFFES\Desktop\REN\blablablabla' does not exi
st.
At C:\Users\STOFFES\Desktop\REN\REN.ps1:2 char:3
+   Rename-Item (Split-Path $_ -Parent) ($_.BaseName)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand`

Even though there are *.nfo files in most of the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Test\Rename" -Include "*.nfo" -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
    $oldFolder = $_.DirectoryName

    # New Folder Name is .nfo Filename, excluding extension
    $newFolder = $_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.Length - 4)

    # Verify Not Already Same Name
    if ($_.BaseName.ToUpper() -ne $newFolder.ToUpper()) {
        Write-Host "Rename: $oldFolder To: $newFolder"

        Rename-Item -NewName $newFolder -Path $oldFolder
    }
}
```

Do you have multiple levels of subfolders?  That's most likely why you're getting 'Cannot rename because item does not exist' errors, because you've already renamed a parent folder.  If that's the case, you'll need something more complex.

Comment: No, it's just one level actually.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
Get-ChildItem *.nfo -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item (Split-Path $_ -Parent) ([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)) -WhatIf
}
```

Requires PowerShell 3+ due to `-File` parameter. Remove `-WhatIf` when ready.

(Aside: The `Where-Object` filter you have in your command is no longer necessary in PowerShell 3.0 and later because it has the `-File` and `-Directory` parameters.)

Comment: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` is not necessary, `$_.BaseName` will suffice

Comment: Why not simply use `($_.BaseName)` instead of `([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name))` ?

Comment: Hi, please see my update the the post. I've running into some problems where some folders aren't renamed.

Comment: Sorry, I tested again and I can't reproduce this.