# Powershell - How to prefix filename into folder for any path containing that file type

Tags: powershell, prefix, basename

Powershell script needed to pull the file basename from a file type within time and date stamped folders on a directory and append those folders with that base name.

The script below works to replace the path name below but I need to prefix the folder. Is it possible to join-path in this way?

[Original link for script below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948530/renaming-folder-with-filename-in-powershell-4-0)

```
cd C:\Directory
Get-ChildItem *.lsa -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item (Split-Path $_ -Parent) ($_.BaseName)  -WhatIf 
}
```

Result:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: C:\Directory\originalpath 
Destination: C:\Directory\basename".
```

What I want is `"C:\Directory\basename_originalpath"`
Or even better would be `"C:\Directory\basename\originalpath"`

I think `Join-path` is the solution but I'm first time scripting and can't link the two commands. I also have to specify the starting directory as the first attempt ran my entire `c:\` drive without it.

Comment: So you would prefer creating a new folder for each `.lsa` file, named the same as the `BaseName` property of the file and then move the file into it?

Comment: That is just my target file. The entire contents of that containing folder need to be in the new folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not pretty but I think this would work:

```
Get-ChildItem *.lsa -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if(-Not (Test-Path -Path "$outputDirectory\$($_.BaseName)")){
        New-Item -WhatIf -ItemType Directory -Path "$outputDirectory\$($_.BaseName)"
    }

    Move-Item (Split-Path $_ -Parent) "$outputDirectory\$($_.BaseName)\$($_.Directory.BaseName)" -WhatIf
}
```

Updated code.

Comment: This is close. The file is always in C:\Directory\dir1\file.lsa so removing the full portion of the path would be nice

Comment: Instead of length, can it just pull every thing from the right side after the C:\Directory\  so just dir1. Then the final would be C:\Directory\file\dir1

Comment: perfect. Thank you!

Comment: How would I run this from a directory file share? eg \\server\share

Comment: after further testing.  instead of C:\Directory\file\dir1 it goes all the way to C:\file\dir1

Comment: Trying to add source and destination in for what you have listed.

Comment: `code`$Source = "C:\Directory\temp"
$Destination = "C:\Directory"
$files = Get-ChildItem $source *.lsa -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if(-Not ("$Destination\$($_.BaseName)")){
        New-Item -WhatIf -ItemType Directory -Path "$Destination\$($_.BaseName)"
    }

    Move-Item "$Destination\$($_.BaseName)\$($_.Directory.BaseName)" -WhatIf
}`code`

Comment: This throws an error that it cannot find the path for the move

Comment: Your Move-Item line needs 2 params - try this: `Move-Item $_.Directory.FullName "$Destination\$($_.BaseName)\$($_.Directory.BaseName)" -WhatIf`

Comment: It is working now. Thank you for all your help